# How does IDA know the symbol names for classes and interfaces?

Tags: ida, c++, symbols, vtables, cutter

I am reversing a 32 bit library used by a Linux game (I am sure someone might recognize the engine used). I was messing around with [cutter](https://github.com/rizinorg/cutter) and when trying to compare it to IDA, which I have used in the past for this library, I noticed that I couldn't search for C++ classes the same way I do with IDA's Ctrl+L.

IDA's output:

[image: IDA Output]

If I search in Cutter's "Symbols" tab:

[image: Cutter symbols]

There is also a "VTable" tab, which also looked interesting since it's basically what I am looking for, but although it shows about 1k VTables, none of them have any kind of name:

[image: Cutter VTable]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class names come from [RTTI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information) descriptors embedded in the binary.

Consider this simple example of retrieving the class of an object at runtime:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

class Base {
public:
    virtual void vvfunc() {}
};

using namespace std;
int main() {
    Base* pb = new Base;
    // class Base
    cout << typeid(*pb).name() << endl;
    // .PEAVBase@@
    cout << typeid(pb).raw_name() << endl;   
    delete pb;
}
```

The second line of the output is a decorated class name - the symbol names used to name VTables are stored in the exact same format. Note that binaries can be stripped off type information at compile time.

An example IDA tool for structuring and parsing RTTI is [ClassInformer](https://github.com/rcx/classinformer-ida7) plugin.

Comment: I have used ClassInformer before, although not for this project, since it only works for windows binaries. While searching around some time ago I saw that since some version ago, IDA has integrated support for RTTI, and I am guessing that's why those names show up in Ctrl+L. I will mark this answer as solved because it contains useful information, but my original issue was that there is a "Classes" window in Cutter that displays all these classes.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that Cutter actually provides RTTI information, but not under the "Symbols" window but under another "Classes" window that is hidden by default.

You can open it from *Windows > Info > Classes*.